# Accessing malloc'ed struct array from called function gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, memory, heap-memory

What I'm basically doing is

- passing a pointer to struct to a function and
- the called function then allocates memory to it by malloc.

Now when I access this memory in Caller function there are no errors.

However if I try to access the same in the called function after allocation.

- there are no errors in accessing first index of array
- But as I try to access the next index of that array it gives segmentation fault

**I'm trying to understand what is happening here or am I missing something.**

[Try it Online result](https://tio.run/##pVJta4MwEP6eX3G0tET7gtbtS20Lg@1XdKVootuBVdE42Ia/3SUarVLZCgtBL3fP3T25J2z1xlhVTTFmUcED2OWCY7J@P5CBK0Jf@QgRn2nAgxBykRVMwPnZEx75JiAXxgLAc6@237OZS0pQ4LNwCflIkEORck8EtHGaJqSpMo1eNZRQZZtNCPZw8aIoYdQBE3L8CpJQpxuG7hXSDrwHy6idTUG10kLkdPKSZUmmS73GE51a1t80k41DOtlsnzjPZMdZIbdELWHeFF62RCW5KYZg13lhklHcWy4g7MCRv8XipnmddsTT6qCuQnFhG6ZtuWMAvwNsxgGsAziWnlKfvrM9zvgJZrzZNX9cDigMTv7gxLqRTIOYY0hISYgS5OJhTFuFtHAgVeypjpJYy6hlY48Mk9ej5HqQCq3fw7zv@02OQQWlhHWvEry56HpchjY6rkEb/UOAh3EBus5X07@aN3O/92Xppo//a1pW1Q8)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Data
{
    int  a;
    int  b;
    int  c;
} Data_t;

void update(Data_t** ppData)
{
    int i;

    *ppData = malloc(3 * sizeof(Data_t));
    if(*ppData == 0)
    {
        puts("Error malloc\n");
    }
    printf("2:Addr = %u %u\n", &ppData, ppData);

    #if 1
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ppData[i]->a = (i+1)*10;
        ppData[i]->b = (i+1)*20;
        ppData[i]->c = (i+1)*30;

        printf("3:[%d] %d %d %d\n", i, ppData[i]->a, ppData[i]->b, ppData[i]->c);
    }
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    Data_t* data;
    int i = 0;

    printf("1:Addr = %u %u\n", &data, data);

    update(&data);

    printf("2:Addr = %u %u\n", &data, data);
    #if 0
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        data[i].a = (i+1)*10;
        data[i].b = (i+1)*20;
        data[i].c = (i+1)*30;

        printf("4:[%d] %d %d %d\n", i, data[i].a, data[i].b, data[i].c);
    }
    #endif
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("5:[%d] %d %d %d\n", i, data[i].a, data[i].b, data[i].c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not referencing your pointer to pointer properly. 

Try using it like this. (*ppData)[i].a = (i+1)*10;

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  When the error condition is from a system function, should also output the text that indicates why the system thinks the error occurred. Suggest using: `perror( "malloc failed" );` which will handly both requirements.

Comment: when an error occurs, that cannot be recovered from, like the call to `malloc()` failing, then after displaying the error info via `perror()`, should 'cleanup' if necessary, the exit the program.  The posted code keeps right on executing the program, as if the call to `malloc()` were successful.

Comment: in general, names that begin with a '_' followed by a capital letter and/or names ending with '_t' are 'reserved' for the system, so 'should' not be generated by user programs.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 3, 10, 20, 30.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for readability and ease of printing, please honor the right margin.  This is usually set to column 72 (or 80).  This can be (usually) easily done by breaking statements at commas and similar delimiters

Comment: in the `update()` function, statements like these: `ppData[i]->a = (i+1)*10;` will not update the desired memory data struct.  Suggest using statements similar to: `(*ppData)[i]->a = (i+1)*10;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing it all wrong.

The access in the called function would be

```
 (*ppData)[i].a = (i+1)*10;
```

`(*ppData)` = The `Data_t*` variable.

Now we allocated 3 memory. And that we are accessing them. And each of which contains structure elements we are accessing them like that.  (`.a` or `.b`) etc.

Whenever you get confused like this, consider step by step.

Like here suppose you allocated it properly. Now think what is `*ppData`? It is of type  `Data_t*`.

Now think that you have `*ppData` with you in a variable called `ptr`.

So what you do now if you have allocated something to `ptr`? You access it like this

```
ptr[i] --> i-th allocated memory
```

What happens if you consider that `ptr[i]` is of type `Data_t`. So you access its elements like this

`ptr[i].a` or `ptr[i].b` etc.

Now here we did same only now we do it over  `*ppData`.

Comment: Oh yes I really missed that point. Really like your step by step approach. Thank You.